# Intercept linux pthread_create function, leading to JVM/SSH crash

Tags: c, linux, ssh, jvm, pthreads

I tried to intercept pthread_create on ubuntu14.04, the code is like this:

```
struct thread_param{
    void * args;
    void *(*start_routine) (void *);
};

typedef int(*P_CREATE)(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,void *
    (*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);

void *intermedia(void * arg){

struct thread_param *temp;
temp=(struct thread_param *)arg;
//do some other things
return temp->start_routine(temp->args);
}

int  pthread_create(pthread_t  *thread,  const pthread_attr_t  *attr,  void  *
(*start_routine)(void  *),  void  *arg){
    static void *handle = NULL;
    static P_CREATE old_create=NULL;
    if( !handle )
    {
        handle = dlopen("libpthread.so.0", RTLD_LAZY);
        old_create = (P_CREATE)dlsym(handle, "pthread_create");
    }
    struct thread_param temp;
    temp.args=arg;
    temp.start_routine=start_routine;

    int result=old_create(thread,attr,intermedia,(void *)&temp);
//        int result=old_create(thread,attr,start_routine,arg);
    return result;
}
```

It works properly with my own pthread_create test case(written in C). But when I used it with hadoop on jvm, it gave me the error report like this:

```
Starting namenodes on [ubuntu]
ubuntu: starting namenode, logging to /home/yangyong/work/hadooptrace/hadoop-2.6.5/logs/hadoop-yangyong-namenode-ubuntu.out
ubuntu: starting datanode, logging to /home/yangyong/work/hadooptrace/hadoop-2.6.5/logs/hadoop-yangyong-datanode-ubuntu.out
ubuntu: /home/yangyong/work/hadooptrace/hadoop-2.6.5/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 131:  7545 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup nice -n 
$HADOOP_NICENESS $hdfsScript --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR $command "$@" > "$log" 2>&1 < /dev/null
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=7585, tid=140445258151680
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_121) (build 1.7.0_121-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.121-b00 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.6.8
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u121-2.6.8-1ubuntu0.14.04.1
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/yangyong/work/hadooptrace/hadoop-2.6.5/hs_err_pid7585.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#]
A: ssh: Could not resolve hostname a: Name or service not known
#: ssh: Could not resolve hostname #: Name or service not known
fatal: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fatal: Name or service not known
been: ssh: Could not resolve hostname been: Name or service not known
#: ssh: Could not resolve hostname #: Name or service not known
#: ssh: Could not resolve hostname #: Name or service not known
#: ssh: Could not resolve hostname #: Name or service not known
^COpenJDK: ssh: Could not resolve hostname openjdk: Name or service not known
detected: ssh: Could not resolve hostname detected: Name or service not known
version:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname version:: Name or service not known
JRE: ssh: Could not resolve hostname jre: Name or service not known
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Or it's because of something else like the protection mechanism of JVM or SSH?
Thank you.

Comment: There is another similar error example: [link](https://sourceware.org/ml/glibc-linux/2001-q1/msg00048.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code causes the child thread to have an invalid `arg` value:

```
    struct thread_param temp;
    temp.args=arg;
    temp.start_routine=start_routine;

    int result=old_create(thread,attr,intermedia,(void *)&temp);
//        int result=old_create(thread,attr,start_routine,arg);
    return result;  // <-- temp and its contents are now invalid
```

`temp` is not guaranteed to exist any more in the new thread as the parent call to your `pthread_create()` may have returned, invalidating the values it contains.

Answer (score 0):

The are a bunch of problems in your code. I don't know which (if any) is causing the problems you're seeing, but you should definitely fix them.

First, you can turn on core dumping (usually using `ulimit -c unlimited`) and load the core in GDB. See what the backtrace points to.

Don't `dlopen` pthreads. Instead, you should just be able to use `dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "pthread_create")`.

The most likely source of the trouble, however, is the fact that you store the original arguments in a global variable. This means that if someone (say, the Java runtime) is simultaneously opening lots of threads, you are going to mix up which is meant to do what.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  For the first point, I am not very familiar with gdb debugging and I turned it on afterwards, but I still cannot figure out the problem. And the second points, if I just use dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "pthread_create"), it will throw warnings and the jvm still will crash. The third point, I am not quite sure which variable is global.  Thank you for your prompt response anyway.